# WPARAM and LPARAM parameters

Tags: c++, api, winapi

When passing a value to a function that takes both a WPARAM and a LPARAM parameter, does it matter on which of them I pass it? Someone told me that if I use Windows x64 I should use WPARAM; is this true?

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows API or a function that you're writing?  If it's something you're writing, describe what the arguments are - there's a good chance that `WPARAM`/`LPARAM` might not be the best way to go.  If it's a Windows API, do what the docs say (should that have to be said?).

Comment: It's something I am writing for a user defined message, I dont even use two parameters, but I saw in a book implemented this way, i just need to pass a string to it, and inside my function i call Postmessage

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When sending messages, `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` parameters have specific interpretations depending on the message. You need to pass those parameters in the way that the message that you are sending expects them to be passed. If you are defining your own message (perhaps via an offset from [`WM_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`WM_APP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`RegisterWindowMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), then you obviously have a bit more latitude.

[In the days of 16-bit Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/25/55850.aspx), a `WPARAM` was a 16-bit word, while `LPARAM` was a 32-bit long. These distinctions went away in Win32; they both became 32-bit values.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `LPARAM` is defined as `LONG_PTR`, which in 64-bit Windows is a signed, 64-bit value. `WPARAM` is defined as `UINT_PTR`, which in 64-bit Windows is an unsigned, 64-bit value. If you are defining your own message, you might want to assign its parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 29):

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║                ║ WPARAM           ║ LPARAM        ║
║                ╟──────────────────╫───────────────╢
║ OS             ║ handles, numbers ║ pointers      ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 16-bit Windows ║ 16-bit unsigned  ║ 32-bit signed ║
║ 32-bit Windows ║ 32-bit unsigned  ║ 32-bit signed ║
║ 64-bit Windows ║ 64-bit unsigned  ║ 64-bit signed ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

The history of its definition has changed over the years.

**WINDOWS.H** (Windows 2.03 SDK, c. 1988)

```
/* Message structure */
typedef struct tagMSG {
    HWND hwnd;
    WORD message;
    WORD wParam;
    LONG lParam;
    DWORD time;
    POINT pt;
} MSG;
```

**WinDefs.h** (c. 1999)

```
/* Types use for passing & returning polymorphic values */
typedef UINT WPARAM;
typedef LONG LPARAM;
typedef LONG LRESULT;
```

**WinDef.h** (c. 2005)

```
/* Types use for passing & returning polymorphic values */
typedef UINT_PTR            WPARAM;
typedef LONG_PTR            LPARAM;
typedef LONG_PTR            LRESULT;
```

### Bonus Reading

- [What do the letters W and L stand for in WPARAM and LPARAM?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031125-00/?p=41713) <sup>*[archive](https://archive.vn/hUc6B)*</sup> *(`W` is for unsigned 16-bit `WORD`, and `L` is for signed 32-bit `LONG`)*
- [What happens to WPARAM, LPARAM, and LRESULT when they travel between 32-bit and 64-bit windows?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110629-00/?p=10303) <sup>*[archive](https://archive.vn/vsOfC)*</sup> *(the unsigned is zero-extended, the signed is sign-extended)*

Comment: Unless I am misreading your table there, you say that an LPARAM cannot hold a pointer in 64-bit windows, is that correct?

Comment: @daramarak I must have gotten that wrong. I swore at the time that it was the case. I remember thinking that 64-bit was like 16-bit world - where there's a size difference between `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`. But i'm going back through header files and i cannot for the life of me find it now. So i guess i was crazy.

Answer (score 6):

It's message-specific. You can use [this list of system-defined message categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_defined) as reference. Select a group, then a message from the group to see what the message specifies you should pass as WPARAM/LPARAM.

Raymond Chen explains [why we have two params](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031125-00/?p=41713).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order matters.  `WPARAM` sent/posted in one side winds up `WPARAM` on the other end; likewise for `LPARAM`.

If you have your own custom messages you can use `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` for anything you want. (There may be some common conventions though.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. I once passed them in swapped order and the function I call fails. Nevertheless, you should consult MSDN when in doubt. I never program in Win64 though, so I don't whether there are differences between Win32 and Win64 regarding `WPARAM`/`LPARAM` behavior.