# Warning C4047 : '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am working on this code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK bWSStatus(HWND hDlg, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int npFlag;

    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        npFlag = (int *)lParam;//Geht in Ordnung, der Wert auf den der Zeiger lParam zeigt ist für npFlag relevant
...
```

I am getting this warning  Warning  C4047 : '=': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: BTW: whenever you see the warning _'foo' differs in levels of indirection from 'bar'_, you should consider it as an error.

Answer (score 4):

Translation of the comment by Google is

> Okay, the value pointed to by the lParam pointer is relevant for npFlag

It seams you forgot to dereference the pointer.

```
// add * to dereference the pointer
npFlag = *(int *)lParam;
```

Comment: I think the `(int*)` cast is unnecessary as `LPARAM` is defined as `typedef unsigned __int3264 ULONG_PTR` in `windows.h`.

Comment: @Dai you think wrong, inspite of it's name, `ULONG_PTR` is not a pointer type.

Comment: @Dai, It's big enough for a pointer, but not actually pointer. See [WPARAM and LPARAM parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6339793/589924) and the typedef in your very own comment