# What is WPARAM and LPARAM in C++ winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

So I've been trying to undersatand why do I put WPARAM and LPARAM when I'm making a C++ window application and I couldn't understand why.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Because the winapi is ancient, from a time computers where still 16 bit and C++ hadn't been invented yet. So the designers back then defined WPARAM, LPARAM so they could change the integer types from 16 to 32 bit later. What you should do is write standard C++ as long as you can, and have a small layer between C++ and the WINAPI that does all conversion closest to the winapi code. If possible don't use the winapi at all and certainly not for threads, file handling etc.

Comment: I recommend **Programming Windows** by Charles Petzold.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6339793/4641116

Comment: Forty years of history based on bad design. Just live with it. :-(